# Best way to implement a button for the SP request to the IdP?

Tags: configuration, webforms, saml-2.0, okta, sustainsys-saml2

So I'm going to preface this by saying SAML (and user auth in general) is not my strong suit, so I apologize for any misused terminology.

**Background:**

We currently have an ASP.Net Framework website, using .Net version 4.7.2 (specifically webforms). Our website acts as a service provider (SP) and currently uses SAML 2.0 with a deprecated identity provider (IdP); luckily, this identity provider is getting replaced with Okta. The original IdP provided their own instructions for implementation which used OWIN middleware and their own NuGet package which configured SAML for us. With Okta though, I found we needed to use a different NuGet package. I've begun configuration for SAML using the [SustainSys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/) packages and made the suggested changes to the web.config (this is our preference over using their OWIN middleware, although I'm open to that, *if* there's a specific reason for it). For additional reference, here is the [sustainsys documentation](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) I was referencing.

**Current Issue:**

The web.config modifications and other changes (such as installing NuGets) have been completed and the website has been cleaned up so as not to cause any errors. However, my biggest question is how to tie it all together now. I understand that our website (the SP) needs to make a request to Okta (the IdP) for the SAML assertion. Unfortunately, I don't understand what I need to send in for that request. I was thinking just a hyperlink to the the IdP SSO link should work, but from what I've read about SAML, there would need to be *some* metadata related to that request. Can anyone suggest how to create a button that would send the necessary metadata? Or clarify if that even needs to be included (perhaps I've misunderstood what needs to be sent)? Also, any additional links or help pertaining to sustainsys (specifically, html or other display elements) would be hugely beneficial.

Thanks

Comment: The Sustainsys documentation for Owin Middleware talks about configuration  of Startup.Auth.cs. did you try it out?  https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/owin-middleware.html

Comment: Yes I added the app.UseSaml2Authentication(new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(true)); line; which from my understanding would signify configuration was coming from the web.config file (ideal in our situation). The OWIN Middleware doesn't seem to outline what to do _after_  adding that though (either configuring SAML there or calling to the config file).

Comment: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleOwinApplication.. This sample application is in MVC and they have loaded the configuration in code and not from web config.  I suggest you to go through this code and implement it as a POC in your test application. Once that works you can then integrate  the code into webforms for your main application.

Comment: Did you got it working?

Comment: No, I actually feel way more confused. I think there's (obviously) a large section of the SAML and OWIN auth concepts that are going over my head. I've been trying to find tutorials that can break these concepts further down for me

Answer (score 2):

To get the Sustainsys.Saml2 library to start the authentication process, you should use the Owin authentication infrastructure to initiate a challenge. That is a general Owin auth concept, and that is why it is not documented in the Sustainsys.Saml2 library.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn343601(v=vs.113)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a sample webform project and connected to Okta using  [Sustainsys Saml2 Owin middleware](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/owin-middleware.html). The code below is just a POC that redirects from Webform Application's to OKTA sign-in page and returns the response back to the configured "Single Sign-On URL" in OKTA. The Code may not have all the necessary security layers. (Security Stamp, Validate Interval)

[image]

**Login.aspx.cs**

If there are more than one external login providers handle the code accordingly.

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        var loginProvider = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes()                         
                                                 .FirstOrDefault();

        AuthenticationManager.Challenge(loginProvider.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the SAML sent by Okta after successful authentication, captured using the Chrome extension
[image: Screenshot of the SAML sent by Okta, captured using the Chrome extension]

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {         
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseSaml2Authentication(new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(true));      
    }       
}
```

**LoginCallback.cs**

Again not completly sure on what code goes into the LoginCallback. But I just checked if the user is Authenticated.

```
public partial class LoginCallback : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        bool isAuthenticated = AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;                   
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first attempt with sustainsys OWIN middleware. The code may not have all the necessary security checks/ best practices. I am learning it along the way.